# Create folder structure based on a datetime list

Tags: python, datetime, file-structure

I have a list of date in datetime format. This list has a range date between `datetime(2018, 1, 1)` to `datetime(2020, 12, 31)`.

I iterate through this list using the following code:

```
 for day in days:
       # code snippet to get data from each day
```

My doubt is: How can use `os.mkdir()` inside my loop to create a folder structure like below

```
    data
       2018
          Jan
            2018-01-01.csv
            2018-01-02.csv
            ...
          Feb
            2018-02-01.csv
            2018-02-02.csv
            ...
          ...
          ...
      2019
         Jan
           ...
         Feb
           ...
         ...
      2020
         Jan
            ...
         Feb
            ...
         ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple folders with `os.makedirs`, it also can ignore if that folder already exists.

```
for day in days:
    path = day.strftime("%Y/%b")
    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
    # write your file to path/filename
```

Or for example:

```
for day in days:
    path = day.strftime(os.path.join("%Y", "%b", "%Y-%m-%d.csv"))
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
    with open(path, "w") as file:
        file.write("Your Data Here")
```

Possible placeholders for `strftime` can be found [on this handy site](https://strftime.org). You might find it useful to change the intermediate folder names, as the month names won't work particularily well with alphabetical order, so you might want to change that to `%m %b` such that the preceding number allows for better sorting.

Comment: Awsome solution! A last doubt, if I want to write a pandas dataframe with `to_csv` method,this method should be call inside `with open(path, "w") as file`?

Comment: @OdiumPura the `to_csv` can directly accept a path and write to it, in that case you can omit the with-block and directly go for `your_df.to_csv(path)` (Following https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: I'm getting permission error - denied access when I try to write file to path using `df.to_csv(path)`. But the folder structure works correctly!

Comment: I used `df.to_csv(path + "/" + filename)`. Now it's working correctly!